# Prove Combination Techniques

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to prove that $\binom{n}{c}\binom{m}{d}\leq\binom{n+m}{c+d}$. I am thinking of plugging in real values to show the proof, but I feel like this is not the correct way to do this. How would one go about proving this?

Answer (score 1):

thinking about how many ways of choosing c from n and d from m, are they already included in choosing c + d from m + n?

Answer (score 0):

(n choose c)*(m choose d) is the number of ways to select c objects from a set of size n and d objects from a set of size m.

(n+m choose c+d) is the number of ways to select c+d objects from a set of size n+m.

Does that help you?

Comment: Um, not really.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of a proof is indeed wrong. When you prove something, you prove it for all possible numbers in the 'domain'. Here lies your first mistake. $n \choose k$ Is only defined for natural numbers ($\mathbb{N}=\lbrace 1,2,3...\rbrace $) $n$  and $k$. So plugging in some arbitrarily numbers is not a rigorous proof.

Rigorous is a keyword in mathematics.

The persons above me gave combinatoric proofs for the inequality. The nice part about those proofs is that they are really intuitive. But they can be hard to 'see'.

Some other tactics for proving statements: By algebraic rewriting of the statement, [Mathematical Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) and some can be proven by pretty pictures! For more tactics/methods: [see this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Methods_of_proof)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.